# Trying to configure a new webpack + angular2 project and I'm getting error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, reflect-metadata

I'm trying to configure a new webpack + angular2 project and I'm getting some errors:

When I use "npm start", I got a lot of errors like this:

```
ERROR in ./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts
(953,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.

ERROR in ./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts
(985,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.

ERROR in ./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts
(1021,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.

ERROR in /home/gchiara/desenvolvimento/honda/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2301,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
```

Here is my code:

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "typings": "typings",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 3000"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/app.ts'
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
  
}
```

polyfills.ts

```js
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'reflect-metadata';

require('zone.js/dist/zone');


if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
  // Production
} else {
  // Development
  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

vendor.ts

```js
// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs';
```

app.ts

```js
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, []);
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  
}
```

The application run normally, but I got tons of errors in console.
Does anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to webpack2 solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because of reflect-metadata@0.1.4.

Downgrade to reflect-metadata@0.1.3 to avoid these errors for the moment!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of dynamic requires in your code I think. The way to get around it is to use the `ContextREplacementPlugin`. At least if you are using webpack 1.x. Maybe webpack2 does this for you.

`new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/reflect/, /^$/)`