# Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried several different configurations to get my **Asp.net mvc 5 project to build with angular2**.
 Somehow I get the error  on the **Reflect.ts**.

> Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient

I tried different versions of packages without any results and im  a bit stuck right now.

I'm not using webpack at all, just Gulp to create the polyfills.

Here my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/core": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/forms": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/http": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.5",
  "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
  "core-js": "2.4.1",
  "systemjs": "0.19.44",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.3",
  "zone.js": "0.7.6",
  "ts-loader": "2.0.0",
  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4"
}
```

And here is the gulp task I use to create the pollyfills...

```
gulp.task("scriptsNStyles", () => {
gulp.src([
        'core-js/client/**',
        'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'reflect-metadata/**',
        'rxjs/**',
        'zone.js/dist/**',
        '@angular/**',
        'jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
        'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.*js'
], {
    cwd: "node_modules/**"
})
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./libs"));
});
```

I hope you have an idea or solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829197/error-ts2384-overload-signatures-must-all-be-ambient-or-non-ambient)

Comment: Im not using webpack....